# How To Write a Monad to Chain Computations Together

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am writing my first monad instance so please forgive if I'm missing something obvious.

I want to do something like this:

```hs
readStuffFromDatabase >>= function1 >>= ... >>= functionN >>= writeStuffToDatabase
```

function1 ... functionN are business logic. Any business logic can return DoNothing which should obviously prevent any further computation.

Here are my questions:

1. Am I thinking about the problem in the right way? Can this approach lead to idiomatic code, good performance, etc. or is it already doomed?
2. How should I define a type intended to chain arbitrary amounts of computation together? What's fuzzy to me is do all monad instances already do that and all I need is a vanilla monad instance? (Like Maybe?) Or do I need something more sophisticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: `Monad` is almost certainly going to paint you into a corner. You need `Applicative` instead, or at most, a selective applicative.

Suppose you go for a monad, name it `M`, and have some action like `numEmployees :: M Int` or something. Now I write:

```
do
    n <- numEmployees
    if n > 10
        then computeTaxes
        else dollars 1000 <$ DoNothing
```

To execute this action, you need to decide whether the `else` branch gets taken before knowing `n`. Not possible.

The fundamental feature of monads that's in your way here is that later actions can inspect the values returned by earlier actions before deciding what to do. Applicative functors do not support that, and so are more amenable to the kind of static analysis you're hoping to do.

Comment: When you say static analysis, do you mean queries will be decided at compile time? If so, that's not what I'm going for. I want queries to be determined at run time.

Comment: Also, can you give me an example of how Applicative would make this easier?

Comment: @JamesStrieter You want queries to be determined at program run time, but at monadic action "compile" time -- i.e. when `readStuffFromDatabase` executes. Right? For example: if `readStuffFromDatabase` was placed after the action in this answer, would you want the `DoNothing` before it to prevent the number of employees from being read? An `Applicative` makes this easier by simply not allowing actions like the one in this answer.

Comment: Gotcha. Let me try to modify the question a bit to encapsulate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I deleted the stuff about getting GHC to figure out the minimum amount of query so now the query happens at the beginning. It's starting to look to me like I might only need Maybe. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @JamesStrieter Sounds right to me. I suspect you already knew, but if you didn't, definitely also take a look at `MaybeT` -- in particular `MaybeT IO` seems relevant if database access has to do `IO` as seems incredibly likely.

Comment: Sweet. Will do. Thank you so much!